# Why IE9 invokes get method instead of post in enter is pressed, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

Enter key is used to post form below.
Pressing enter sends get request Iin IE9:
  first enter sends get, second enter sends post, third enter send get request etc.

How to send only post request if enter is pressed ?
In firefox, only post request is sent properly.

```
<form id="Form" method='post' target='DocumentRegisterReportpdf'
    action='/erp/Report/Render?_entity=DocumentRegisterReport'>
... form fields

<select class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="_Report" name="_Report" size="10">
<option selected="selected" value="AKART001">Report1</option>
<option value="A3001">Report2</option>
<option value="A3003">Report3</option>
</select>

<input id='_submit' type='submit' value='Show PDF' />
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#_Report').keypress(function (e) { if (enter(e)) { $('#Form')[0].submit(); cancel(e); } });
            $('#_submit').focus();
        });

function enter(e) { return e.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.ENTER && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey; }

function cancel(evt) {
    evt.returnValue = false;
    evt.keyCode = 0;
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
}
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#_Report').keypress(function (e) { 
    if (enter(e))
        {
            var action = $('#Form').attr('action'),
                separator = action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&',
                url = action + separator + $('#Form').serialize(),
                post_or_get = 'post';
            $.ajax({
                 url : url,
                 method : post_or_get, 
                 success : function(data){
                     // this is the callback :)
                 }
            });
        }
});
```

or you could clone the form, change it's method from `post` to `get` and submit it :

```
$('#_Report').keypress(function (e) { 
    if (enter(e))
        {
             var post_or_get = 'post';
             $('#Form')
                 .clone()
                 .attr('method', post_or_get)
                 .submit();
        }
});
```

Comment: your code sends only get request. I asked to send only post request. The issue was that pressing enter shows get and post requests sequentially for unknown reason. How to send `post` request only?

Comment: I tried updated methods in IE9. ajax call sends `get` request every time. clone() method does not send any request, it looks like submit() call is ignored. How to send post request on enter ?

Comment: question contains `target='DocumentRegisterReportpdf'` . Your ajax call does not open result in new tab. Also, your ajax calls tries passes form data in url. For big amount of data data gets truncated. for post request buffer shoud used instead.